# Confusion about distance metric used in limit proof

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I was looking at the proof that for a bounded and monotonic sequence, the sequence converges to the sup/inf if it is increasing/decreasing. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Proof

However, this seems to assume that we're using the standard metric for our definition of limit, without which, the result doesn't seem to hold in general. For instance, if $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the discrete metric, the sequence does not converge if the sequence is strictly monotonic. Why is this assumption not stated?

Comment: When talking about the convergence of a sequence of real numbers, it is usually implicitly assumed that unless otherwise stated, you are working with the standard notion of limit...

Answer (score 0):

Real analysis is always over the real numbers, ordered Archimedian field with order or topological completeness.

Your question would at least require that the order structure and the metric are compatible. This is not true for the discrete metric.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how exactly the order and the metric are required to relate to one another (and where this requirement comes from)?

Comment: At least the bounded open sets should be the same in the order and metric topology.